# in the VBA function Split(a,b)(0) what does the second bracket represent?

Tags: excel, vba

Note; I am new to VBA, the code snippet is from a code that has been handed to me, which does not have comments.

In the following sample script

```
item = Split ( apples, "-")(0)
```

is the second bracket (0) the "compare" argument 

the *apples*  the expression

the "-" the delimiter?

Or is the (0) interpreted as the limit ?

because the format is different in MS's documentation

Split(expression, [ delimiter, [ limit, [ compare ]]])

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Comment: That line does two things (1) Creates an array using `Split()` (2) Accesses the first element of that array via `(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Split` makes an array out of a string. In your case, `-` is the delimiter (i.e., that character that separates the string into pieces that will become elements of the array) and the `(0)` means you want the first element of that array. `(1)` would be the second element and so on.

So, for example

```
my_string='This-is-a-string'
my_string_part=Split(my_string, "-")(0)
```

`my_string_parts` will hold `This`.

Answer (score 0):

`Split` returns a 0-based array, so the `(0)` accesses the first element of it.

If `apples = "This-is-a-test"` then `Split ( apples, "-")(0)` returns `"This"`.